# Update from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, sql-update

can you please help me with the following update statement used with join from multiple tables:

```
  update rol
  set
  rol.role_name = GetCode('ADDRTYPE', ao.Addr_Typ)
  FROM table_addr ao ,
       table_contact con ,
       table_role rol 
  where con.appid = rol.id
  AND ao.use_id = con.con_id
  and rol.role_name='Corporate'
```

I am getting Oracle error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Have a look at [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

Comment: @Aleksej - Why? What is the benefit of MERGE over UPDATE in this case?

Comment: @SocketM - Does the error message give you the line number and position?

Comment: Yes is on the line (4) FROM table_addr ao , column 3

Comment: @mathguy because Oracle doesn't support updates with joins in that format.

Comment: @Boneist - true, but if one has to rewrite the query anyway, why not just fix the update statement to follow proper syntax? I see the OP solved the problem exactly that way.

Comment: @Boneist sure, it's possible to do that - as the OP has proved. However, for this type of update, I find that the merge statement is easier to understand and maintain than the corresponding correlated query. Especially when the correlated query is being used as a parameter to a function call. YMMV, of course, but where's the harm in suggesting alternative ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Oracle doesn't support updates from joins like that, a merge statement is probably your best bet.

Something like:

```
merge into table_role tgt
using (select ao.addr_typ,
              con.appid
       from   table_addr ao
              inner join table_contact con on (ao.use_id = con.con_id)) src
  on (tgt.id = src.appid)
when matched then
  update set tgt.role_name = getcode('ADDRTYPE', src.addr_typ)
  where  role_name = 'Corporate';
```

This assumes that `appid` in the src query is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Update doesn't support support FROM key word ([See Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html)). My working solution

is:

```
      update table_role rol
  set
  role_name = GetCode('ADDRTYPE',
 ( select distinct ao.Addr_Typ 
   FROM table_addr ao ,
        table_contact con 
  where con.appid                  = rol.id
  AND ao.use_id          = con.id
  )

  )
  where
  role_name='Corporate'
```

Comment: Hi, - the preferred join syntax (recommended even by Oracle over their own, old-style syntax you used) is `from table_addr ao inner join table_contact con on ao.use_id = con.id where con.appid = rol.id`